# Google Maps: Marker will not show up?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

```
"use strict"; // eslint-disable-line


var map;
var initialLocation;
// TODO: Initialize and display Google Map
function initialize() {
    //get current location


  if(navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      initialLocation = new         google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
      map.setCenter(initialLocation);
    }, function() {
      handleNoGeolocation(browserSupportFlag);
    });
  }

var mapProp = {
center:initialLocation,
zoom:6,
    mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: initialLocation,
          map: map
        });


}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

I am trying to set a marker to my current location using Javascript. When I load the map, however, while the map will center on my current location, no marker will appear?

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks good, just add  ***marker.setPosition(initialLocation);*** in the following section:

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
    marker.setPosition(initialLocation);// ****** missing line ******
    map.setCenter(initialLocation);
  }, function() {
    handleNoGeolocation(browserSupportFlag);
  });
};
```

Here is a working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sleonard947/Lq3qcurg/6/) with the necessary changes.

The key is from a Google MAP API sample and will need to be updated with your own, which you can obtain here: [Google MAP API](https://developers.google.com/maps/get-started/).

You may need to reload the JSFiddle example, as there appears to be an issue with the async defer coming from googleapis file.  Wait a few seconds and press RUN.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure the content of variable  initialLocation.
If it has the correct lon/lat, marker will appear.
You have to make sure it has correct value before the following:
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: initialLocation,
          map: map
        });